# What tool for Sum/Average/Count within x distance of each raster cell using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator

I'm looking for an alternate way to undertake some processing.

Is there an ArcGIS Pro toolbox tool that can take an existing raster, use each cell (cell centroid?) to produce a new raster that contains the Count/Average/Sum/Etc of the cells within x distance?

So, lets say I had a raster where cells with houses present was a value 1, and everything else was a 0, I could produce a second raster with the input query being "for each cell give me the sum of all cells within 500m". The output is a new raster with the same cell boundaries (origin, width, etc - a snap raster in ESRI terms) where each cell is a count.

My current workflow would be to take the raster, convert it to points, buffer the points by 500m and produce individual polygons, ensure all datasets had a spatial index, summarize within / zonal statistics, join the resultant table back to the points, create the raster from points. It's horribly inefficient. The issue is I can't seem to work out if there's a tool to do it all within raster processing. If one exists - I do not know it's name and can't seem to find it.

Comment: Have a look at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm. Your question is ambiguous in terms of raster representation that is used. Does each cell (value of 1) corresponds to one house unit or is it a result of polygon to raster conversion where each building is represented by lots of 1s? The outcome of this tool can differ what is represented by a cell.

Comment: Also, generate near table from https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/commonly-used-tools/proximity-analysis.htm.

Comment: Thanks, although BERA already indicated what is most probably the best tool for the job. I think you have misunderstood the intent. Near describes what is near, not the aggregate of what is nearby when using an iteration over each cell of a raster (similar to a roving carat) by retaining the underlying structure of the raster. I also left out a specific case because the question was about a tool with particular capabilities, not how to approach a particular problem. I have a few scenarios to which the logic would apply, but didn't have the name of the tool at hand.

Comment: In fact what BERA said is same as what i said in my first comment. i also preferred to highlight some ambiguities in your question. Anyway, i am glad you have found an efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Focal Statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/focal-statistics.htm):

> Calculates for each input cell location a statistic of the values
> within a specified neighborhood around it.